# Tortoisesvn - hiding apikey

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I've just started using tortoisesvn for windows and have some code I want to publish.

The code contains a apikey that obviously I wont want the world to see. If there anyway in tortoise to strip this out?

I dont want to permanently remove it from source otherwise when I compile it locally things will stop working.

Answer (score 0):

1. Save all your credentials into a separate file, e.g. `parameters.foo` (where foo is the actual extension of the language you are using).
2. Right click on the file and choose "TortoiseSVN → Add to ignore list → parameters.foo".
3. Create a copy of the file, e.g. `parameters.foo.dist`.
4. Edit the copy to remove actual data, e.g. replace `API_KEY='abcdefg` with `API_KEY=''`.
5. Commit that file into the repository

This technique is described in the Subversion FAQ entry [I have a file in my project that every developer must change, but I don't want those local mods to ever be committed. How can I make 'svn commit' ignore the file?](http://subversion.apache.org/faq.html#ignore-commit).